# Android Alarm Manager not being triggered

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have my app installed in 2000 devices. In most of them it is working great. But some users (maybe 100) report me that the app is not updating correctly.

I found out that the problem is that the AlarmManager is not triggering an Alarm. The app is supposed to update data every 15 minutes so I use an Alarm Manager for that.

With no reason, it seems like it stops working after a while of running and it never starts again unless the phone is rebooted. Then it works again for a while and finishes stopping, too.
I don't have access to those devices but the users tell me they don't have any task manager or background cleaners. And in case they have them, then my app is in the 'ignore list'.

I have tried to emulate this scenario but I cannot.

It seems like the app is killed and the alarm managers don't work. By the way, those killed apps don't receive GCM events either.

So the questions are:

1. Is there anyway to prevent the app from being killed or to ensure the alarm is triggered at the time I set.
2. Can I use broadcast events like Screen-on, Screen-Off or Telephony incoming events to check if the alarm has been triggered and in case it is not to do it at that moment? I am not sure if this would work because if my app is killed then probably it will not receive any event, correct?

Comment: have You asked which devices they have? I have Huawei Ascend Mate 7, there is an Huawei Energy Manager integrated (open it from settings). There the apps has to be protected. The problem is, that can not be done programmatically, You have to tell them......

Comment: Oh ok thanks. There are several brands and several Android releases. I cannot find a pattern. The problem also is that the users don't interact much, they don't give much information and I had never had one of those devices in my hands to analyze it.

Comment: yeah, I know the problem. You could be glad if some user contacts You before givin a bad vote, there is nothing You can do but givin a hint for example at the app start, like a dialog with the short information.....

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html?